# Stream.CopyTo throws System.OutOfMemoryException C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to load a large video file (250mb) into my browser. The file is large so I am trying to load a certain number of bytes at a time, but it appears the problem lies somewhere else as I have tried changing the bufferSize with no results.

```
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(Server.MapPath(path), FileMode.Open))
    {
        fs.CopyTo(ms, 10000);
    }
```

The exception is thrown at the CopyTo method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn‘t matter how many bytes you load at a time. At the end you still have to load everything into memory.

Comment: Do you need to copy the file to the MemoryStream at all? could you just use `fs` where you are using `ms` later on in your code?

Comment: Why do you need a MemoryStream at all, how are you playing the video then?

Comment: @CSharpie Prior to this, I was just setting the video src to the variable "path". With this code here, I was trying to load small parts of the video at a time prior to playing it, thinking it was just trying to load too much at once.

Comment: What is your end goal here? You want to get this video and do what? Store it on the disk? Play it streaming? Right now, you are simply storing it in memory and that is potentially causing your out-of-memory issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have learned a valuable lesson. Set your application platform target to 64bit rather than 32bit when trying to load larger files. Also do the same for IIS Express that Visual Studio launches in Tools>Options>Project and Solutions> Web Projects. This has resolved my problem, maybe it will help someone else. I appreciate everyone's comments!

Comment: This might fail when the File is larger than 2GB -- the runtime doesn't allow objects (usually: byte arrays) larger than 2GB, and the reference source ( https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs ) doesn't look as if MemoryStream splits your data into multiple parts, stored in different arrays.

Answer (score 4):

Steam.CopyTo does not link the streams to let them copy the data on demand, but copies all data immediately.

The memory stream is intended to hold all data in memory permanently -- which is not always a good idea with large files -- even if the temporary copy buffer is small.

You could try to use the filestream itself, or if this causes performance problems, a BufferedStream might help you -- that one only keeps some parts of the file in memory.